# Get and Add like(Favourite or Unfavourite) product in Magento 2 Rest API With URL?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, api, rest-api, wishlist

Get Favourite product in Magento 2 REST API with URL?

And Add to Favourite in Magento 2 REST API with URL?